# Read dynamic control's value after PostBack for custom paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, postback, viewstate

I've created a custom paging class -`Pagger`- to implement paging for listing controls.

now, The `Pagger` object generates an `ASP:Panel` that contains the navigation btns -`ASP:LinkButton`- that responsible for navigation, each generated btn stores inside it the `pageNumber`it must navigates to

**Example:**
[image]

To enhance the paging I used Ajax -`ASP:UpdatePanel`- to surround the `paging panel`,
now, on each `btn's click` a `PostBack` happens, so I re-created all the `btns` in `OnPreInit` page event to let them be available again -that is obvious, and that is not the question-

```
 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Pagger p = new Pagger(itemsCount, itemsPerPage);

        //Here the pager reads from viewstate to know 
        //which pageNumber is the currentPage and generates btns according to it
        p.GeneratePaggerPanel(CurrentPageNumber);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(p.PaggerPanel);

        //link the LinkBtn to event handler to be executed upon clicking
        foreach (Control c in p.PaggerPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (c is LinkButton)
            {
                ((LinkButton)c).Click += Button1_Click;
            }
        }
        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
```

now, in order to know which `pageNumber` is the `currentPageNumber` I went to store it in the `ViewState`

```
public uint CurrentPageNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["CurrentPageNumber"] != null)
                return (uint)ViewState["CurrentPageNumber"];
            return 1;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["CurrentPageNumber"] = value;
        }
    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    CurrentPageNumber = ((PaggerLinkButton)sender).Tag;
 }
```

but `btnEvent Click` triggers after the `page_load`, thats mean the `ViewState` wont be available when `re-creating` the `pager btns` in `OnPreInit` event
how can I set the `ViewState` value by reading the `pressed btn's value` before initializing the `pager btns panel` so that pager can use the `currentPageNumber` in the same `PostBack` and do not wait to do another `PostBack`?

I've also read [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages) but nothing really helped me.

P.S.: the `PaggerLinkButton` is inherited from `LinkButton` with one new property `Tag`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options (that I can think off).

1. Replace the server-side Button1_click method a client side click event handler for your link buttons. This client side method should set the page value to a hidden control on the form. Note you don't need custom linkbutton class with the tag attribute. Simply set the page value on the client side onclick handler code (something like, OnClick='setPageNo(x); return true;'). Then within OnPreInit get the currentpagenumber from the hidden control.
2. I am not sure why you are recreating PaggerPanel control in each postback (as opposed to relying on viewstate) but, you should be able to separate the logic in GeneratePaggerPanel method to (a) Panel creation myPanel = p.GeneratePaggerPanel() which is done in OnPreInit and (b) currentpage specific changes p.FixPaggerPanel(myPanel, CurrentPageNo) which is done within the Button1_click method.

Hope this helps,
cheers,
Nick